# How to extract bar heights from histogram

Tags: histograms

In mathematica I have plotted a histogram with the PDF option from a list of values.

How can I extract the heights of the bars in the histogram so that I can compare them with those of another histogram?

Comment: Maybe you could use `BinCounts`

Comment: @mattiav27 That is helpful. I don’t even need a histogram anymore!

Answer (score 3):

Try examplary

```
h = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]]
```

[image]

The bars might be found inside `h` as Rectangle-objects:

```
bars=Cases[Normal@h , Rectangle[a_, b_, c_] :> {a, b}, Infinity]    (*{{{-3., 0}, {-2.5, 2.}}, {{-2.5, 0}, {-2., 2.}}, {{-2., 0}, {-1.5, 
10.}}, {{-1.5, 0}, {-1., 11.}}, {{-1., 0}, {-0.5, 31.}}, {{-0.5, 
0}, {0., 39.}}, {{0., 0}, {0.5, 34.}}, {{0.5, 0}, {1., 34.}}, {{1.,
0}, {1.5, 24.}}, {{1.5, 0}, {2., 10.}}, {{2., 0}, {2.5, 
2.}}, {{3.5, 0}, {4., 1.}}}*)
```

The heights follow to

```
Map[#[[2, 2]] &, bars]
(*{2., 2., 10., 11., 31., 39., 34., 34., 24., 10., 2., 1.}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
```

You can use [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) directly on `data`:

```
HistogramList[data][[2]]
```

> ```
> {2, 6, 25, 15, 45, 35, 39, 20, 7, 3, 3}
> ```

If you have access only to an histogram output (not `data`) , you can extract the `Tooltip` labels to get the bar heights:

```
h = Histogram[data]
```

[image]

```
Cases[h, Tooltip[_, Style[t_, ___]] :> t, All]
```

> ```
> {2, 6, 25, 15, 45, 35, 39, 20, 7, 3, 3}
> ```

**Note:**  Default bin specifications for  [`BinCounts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinCounts.html) and `HistogramList` are different:

[image]

[image]

So  `BinCounts` does not give the same output:

```
{BinCounts[data], HistogramList[data][[2]]}
```

> ```
> {{2, 31, 60, 74, 27, 6}, {2, 6, 25, 15, 45, 35, 39, 20, 7, 3, 3}}
> ```