# How can I keep a distance to the abscissa axis when specifying an AxisLabel in the form "text"?

Tags: labeling, histograms

These observations are from Mathematica 12.3.0.0 on Linux x86 (64 Bit).

With `AxisLabel->{"A", "number"}` the character `A` sometimes slips directly to the end of the abscissa in the context of Histogram, especially if the histogram has a few outliers far to the right. Even a few spaces before the abscissa label, like `AxisLabel->{"     A", "number"}` do not improve it.

[image: a histogram with outliers and unreasonable positioning of abscissa axis label]

If you call `Histogram` for the same data with the option `PlotRange->All`, then there remains a reasonable distance between the end of the axis. Then, of course, all extreme outliers are displayed on the abscissa (or they are not visible after all, because such small frequencies are lost in the display).

The displayed data (extracted from the histogram as described in [How to extract bar heights from histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259371/how-to-extract-bar-heights-from-histogram) are:

```
{{10.,9},{15.,405},{20.,8117},{25.,7738},{30.,9708},{35.,24467},{40.,42348},{45.,18129},{50.,43195},{55.,63039},{60.,16491},{65.,20030},{70.,17563},{75.,5361},{80.,19886},{85.,17787},{90.,14283},{95.,7998},{100.,3945},{105.,5469},{110.,808},{115.,1839},{120.,5501},{125.,1491},{130.,552},{135.,231},{140.,102},{145.,175},{150.,95},{155.,235},{160.,202},{165.,147},{170.,490},{175.,286},{180.,668},{185.,164},{190.,52},{195.,76},{200.,40},{205.,15},{210.,3},{220.,4},{225.,8},{230.,2},{235.,1},{240.,1},{245.,3},{255.,1},{260.,1},{275.,1}}
```

so the few outliers right of A=145 cause the wrong `AxisLabel`-behaviour in this case. Is it a bug? How can one overcome it without stretching the histogram to display all the not really relevant outliers?

Comment: Is this behavior related to the ImageSize?

Comment: The histogram is created with ` Print[Histogram[...  , AxesLabel -> {"A", "number"}, ImageSize -> {400}]]`